# adding list of tuples to a new tuple in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like the following

```
list=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

now I need to add them to a new tuple `tup=()`

my resultant tuple should look like `tup=((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))`

I tried using the following code:

```
 for each in list:

    tup=tup,each
```

the result is

```
(((), (627, 2)), (627, 3))
```

Can someone help me solving this?

Comment: `list` is a built in function, use a different variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to convert with `tuple` function :

```
>>> my_list=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> tuple(my_list)
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

note : dont use the built-in functions name or python keywords as your structure and variables name!